# Outlook 2010 keeps losing the search index for emails

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook, search, microsoft-outlook-2010

Hoping someone can help here, this is driving me insane.

Outlook 2010 keeps losing the search index so when I search for an email it has the yellow bar saying:

> search results may be incomplete
>   because items are still being indexed

Clicking on the bar says eg:

> 49200 items remaining to be indexed

If it makes any difference, this is an IMAP account. If I leave Outlook open all day it will eventually index everything. But then say a week/month later it happens all again.

Comment: I have the same problem w/ Outlook 2010, but w/ exchange instead of imap.  Rebuilt PST files, reset search, the whole nine yards.  Search on Outlook is CRAP.

Comment: @Marcus, Did you have any luck figuring out what caused this?

Comment: Unfortunately not @David, swapped to using an online email system rather than Outlook.

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully one of these steps will help solve the problem. Source: http://www.msoutlook.info/question/47

> There are a couple of levels at which Instant Search in Outlook 2007
>   and 2010 can break. You can troubleshoot Instant Search in the
>   mentioned order in this article.
>
> **Marked for indexing**
>
> First let us check if the pst-file has been marked
>   to be indexed. To do this go to;  Tools-> Options-> Search Options… In
>   the Indexing section you can select which data file to index.
>
> When you are using Outlook 2010, you can do this via;  File->
>   Options-> section Search-> button Indexing Options…-> button Modify->
>   expand Microsoft Outlook  In the list that is shown under Microsoft
>   Outlook, make sure that your pst-file is displayed and selected. If it
>   is not listed, you’ll have to recreate your mail profile.
>
> *Locations selected to be indexed in Outlook 2007.*
>
> **Check for pst-file corruptions**
>
> If your pst-file has been marked but
>   Outlook doesn’t display the correct results, it usually means there is
>   some corruption going on in your pst-file. In order to fix these you
>   should scan your pst-file for errors with scanpst.exe. You can find
>   this file in the same folder as outlook.exe or use OutlookTools
>   (free!) to locate it for you.
>
> Once repaired, open Outlook and leave it idle for some time. To see if
>   everything has been indexed now go to Tools-> Instant Search->
>   Indexing Status.  For Outlook 2010 you must click in the Search field
>   in order to make the Search Tools tab visible in the Ribbon. Here
>   click the Search Tools button and select the Indexing Status…
>
> When you have a big pst-file this indexing could take some time but if
>   the number of items left to index doesn’t change after leaving your
>   computer idle for over 30 minutes something is wrong still.
>
> **Disable and then re-enable the file for indexing**
>
> Go back to the Search
>   Options and deselect the data file that is giving you issues. Close
>   Outlook and wait for about 5 minutes and also verify in Task Manager
>   (CTRL+SHIFT+ESC) that on the Processes tab the outlook.exe process
>   actually quits. You might get a lot of disk activity; this is the
>   Search Indexer removing the indexed items from the Index.
>
> After this open Outlook again and go back to the Search Option and
>   select the pst-file we just deselected. Leave the computer idle again
>   and see if it will eventually reach the status of "0 items remaining."
>
> **Rebuild the index**
>
> If it doesn’t, it might be that the Index itself has
>   been damaged. In order to reset this, go to Control Panel-> Indexing
>   Options-> Advanced-> button Rebuild
>
> This will rebuild the entire Index from scratch and depending on the
>   amount of documents to be indexed, this could take quite long and
>   degrade your system’s performance while the Indexer is still busy. I
>   would recommend to have it rebuild itself overnight.
>
> *Advanced Indexing Options in Windows 7.*
>
> **Reset the index**
>
> If it still doesn’t work press the “Restore Defaults”
>   button that you can find under the Rebuild button in Windows Vista.
>   The difference with Rebuild is that, aside from resetting all
>   customized indexing settings like indexing location and file type
>   selections, it will recreate the actual Index files as well.
>
> In Windows 7, you can press the blue “Troubleshoot search and
>   indexing” link. This will start a troubleshooting wizard in which you
>   can select the option “E-mail doesn’t appear in search results”.
>
> **Check Event Viewer and post in the newsgroups**
>
> Still running into
>   indexing issues? It might be good to take a look in the Event Viewer
>   and look for any errors logged by the “Search” or “Microsoft Outlook”.
>   If the error logged there is not helpful to you, post it in the
>   Outlook newsgroups together with your configuration details in order
>   to help you troubleshoot it.

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't help. Just lost it again after a month or so.

Comment: Oh... bugger maybe there is a more deep seated problem like clean-up software being a bit overzealous or just a problem with Windows (need a clean install) or hardware (may need new hardware). Could also just be a different problem, you would need to try and find out exactly when this happens or why or if it always happens after a certain action?